# Delete data from mysql tables when a user clicks the refresh button

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a site that updates a mysql table when the user adds some information, however if the user clicks the refresh button, i need those records to be deleted. Is there a way to accomplish this with javascript? I am new to jquery so i would prefer to avoid it.

I cannot use mysql transactions since i am using different php files and ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript, you can use the onunload event to check for refresh and AJAX to call your PHP functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onunload = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;

        if(y < 0)  alert("Window closed");
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "functionsFolder/myFunction.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! that is very helpful! This script would work for both refreshing and closing the site?

Comment: Thank you i used the onunload and onload functions to call my ajax functions and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to add or update multiple rows to a database when the user types it but when they click refresh, the data should revert back again?

The big question is, why update the database in the first place? It doesn't seem to achieve much and is just adding to the complexity of the application. If the altered rows are never to be written to the database then there is no point in using

If you **really** what to use a database table for storing temporary data then create a holding table which new/updated rows go into and only commit that data when navigating away.

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought, i created two temporal tables and linked an ajax function to the onload function so i can now that the page was refreshed and seems to work fine. Now my problem is that i added an "onbeforeunload" event to know when the user leaves the site but how would i know that he clicked on the "Leave this page" button?

Comment: Create a handler for the "Leave this page" button which will fire off an ajax request to transfer everything from the holding table to the main one.

Comment: I just looked at your other question regarding keeping MySQL transactions open across separate scripts and I'm guessing that this question is related to that. You'd probably be better off holding all this information in a cookie rather than a table. You could then set up a couple of handlers to either write or discard the data in the cookie to the DB depending on the button clicked. Also, search for information regarding "shopping basket" implementations - why re-invent the wheel for something so common?

Comment: How would i create the handler for the leave this page button?

Comment: Regarding the other question, i get what you mean but i have a close deadline and so far the tables are working, maybe in a second stage i would implement the cookies.

Comment: If you've already created a handler for the "onload" function, you should be able to create one for the "leave" button. To be honest, jQuery isn't too scary once you get into it and takes away a lot of hassle when creating AJAX requests and handlers - I'm new to it too and have managed to figure it all out over the course of a few days and now have a site which handles all user requests via AJAX (dynamically loading sub-forms, retrieving/handling data, etc)